# get him to project - what is the correct phrase to say this?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

I am a team lead, I selected a person. i need to update to my manger as like this:

`Get him to On Board to the Project.`

Is this correct? or Is there any other phrase to express this?

Comment: Also as a side note, the title's "Get him to project" is a valid sentence, however with a different meaning. Project in that sentence would mean 'convey message' in essence, you can project sentences (as you do when you speak, or in particular, speaking loudly) and also other less obvious communications such as projecting emotions or body language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get him on board with the project** is the popular phrase for introducing someone to a project.

> **on board**
>
> if someone is on board, they are working with an organization or group
> of people A new financial director has been brought on board to help
> us assess the cost of the project. We hope to have a new doctor on
> board by the end of the month.
>
> [The Free Dictionary (idioms)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+board)

In your case, you want to introduce a person to the team, so you want to get them on board, or in particular you wanted them to be on board with the project, which means that they will work as part of and towards the projects goals.